# cin.getline () is not working when called the second time

Tags: c++, getline

In this code ,getline is not working for i =1 .but for i = 0 it is working completely fine.
What I should do to repeatedly work with the getline function.This code takes a number and checks its divisibility."numb" is taken to store the number.for i = 0 all the calcultions are just fine but when it goes for the 2nd turn ,don't know what happens but cin.getline doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#define MAX 1050 
using namespace std ;

int call_div (char *num ,long div)
{
    int len =strlen (num) ;
    int now ;
    long extra ;
    for (now = 0,extra=0; now < len; now += 1)
    {
        extra = extra *10 + (num [now] -'0') ;
        extra = extra %div ;
    }
    return extra ;
}

int main (int argc, char const* argv[])
{       
    int testcase,numbers ,flag =0;
    char numb[MAX] ;
    cin >> testcase ;
    getchar() ;


    for (int i = 0; i < testcase; i += 1)
    {
        cout << i << endl ;

        int div[14] ; 
        cin.getline(numb) ; // i= 0 ,it works fine ,i=1 ,it doesn't work
        cin >> numbers ;

        for (int j = 0; j < numbers; j += 1)
        {
            cin >> div[j] ;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < numbers; k += 1)
        {

            //   cout << div[k]<< ' '   << call_div (numb,div[k]) << endl ;
            if (call_div (numb,div[k])==0)
            {
                flag = 1 ;
            }
            else {
                flag = 0 ;
                break;
            } 
        }
        if (flag==0 )
        {
            cout << "simple"<< endl  ;
        }
        else
            cout << "wonderful" << endl  ;

    }       
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. Use `std::getline`. 2. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20getline%20skipping

Comment: Can you post the output you currently obtain and what you would expect? (and your inputs)

Comment: `char numb[MAX];` followed by an unchecked `getline(cin,numb);` is a buffer overflow waiting to happen. It would be better to use `std::string`s.

Answer (score 1):

I think Your input may look like

```
something
3 1 2 3
some other thing
4 1 2 3 4
```

First time You read "something" with `getline()`. Then your algorithm reads the 3 as `numbers`, and then the three number followed by that one. And here reading stops. Next time You call `getline()`, it will continue reading until it reaches the first `'\n'` character. So it will not read "some other thing" when You want it.

Now I can not try it, but I think it will work fine with an extra "dumb" `getline()` after the loop that fills the `div` array.